# Quotation at the beginning of a chapter

Tags: quotation

Hi would like to put a quotation at the beginning of each chapter. I am using "jurabook" and I just don't how to do it since I cannot use \dictum. I would much appreciate any help!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt,titlepage]{jurabook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek.ancient,english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{betababel}
\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
%\usepackage{typearea}
%\typearea{12}
\usepackage{newcent}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{microtype}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\enquote{To Be or Not to Be.}
Shakespeare

\end{document}
```

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193349/how-to-make-chapter-and-part-align-right-and-get-a-quote-under-them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

One way to do quotes at the start of chapters is with the [`epigraph`](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/epigraph/epigraph.pdf) package.

I've removed some packages for simplicity:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt,titlepage]{jurabook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % For filler text
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\epigraph{To Be or Not to Be.}{Shakespeare}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The general syntax is

```
\epigraph{QUOTE}{SOURCE}
```

Comment: Is there a way to position it further north without pushing the text down?

Comment: I think I have found the solution, at least for me current case. I used \epigraphhead[70]{\epigraph{Quote}{Source}}